# Eclipse EclEmma Find where code tested

Tags: eclipse, eclemma

Is there a way in Eclipse with or without the EclEmma plugin to find the actual test where the code in question has been tested? After searching online, I doubt it can be done, just wanted to ask here to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Upon a line highlighted Green or Yellow by EclEmma, set a breakpoint!

Then rerun (rather Debug) the tests :-)  Not the fastest, but it'll get the job done.

Comment: I think it does. Quote: "Is there a way **in Eclipse** with **or without** the EclEmma plugin ..." This is a trick to apply after using EclEmma, when browsing it's results. Anyway thanks, I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: sorry, seems like a misclick from me (although the topic is on the edge of being off-topic)